# What does `::` mean in php magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

In the below code what does the `::` operator mean or do?

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
```

Also what does the `helper` do exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of PHP `::` is a [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php). Used to access static elements of a Class.

In Magento, `Mage::helper()`, here `helper()` is a STATIC function listed in `Mage.php` file, like `public static function helper($name)`.

From your exampe, `Mage::helper('catalog/category')`, this will return an Object of `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category` helper. Check this line in `helper` function definition, `$helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);`

Comment: The double colon - scope resolution operator is also known as a Paamayim Nekudotayim. Although in 10 years in software development, I'm yet to encounter someone who can pronounce it, or spell it without looking it up, myself included. :)

Answer (score 5):

in PHP, **`:: specify scope resolution operator,`**

Its  native php functionality for **`getting static function,variable`** from php file.

```
Mage::helper() means static helper function is defined inside `app/Mage.php file`.
```

first get helper function from **`Mage.php`** file,

```
 public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }
```

Helper function is called first from `mage.php` file when you can use any helper in module. They define module full path to access it.

You can get more info about this using link, [Scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category')
```

Now **$_helper** variable get access to all function of `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category.php` file

If you want to fetch `getStoreCategories()` functions from above file,
you can simple call `$_helper->getStoreCategories(false,false,true)` and return store category object.